# Kendo Grid EditorTemplateName - Client side binding

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I was working with a Kendo Editor Template in two seperate solutions, where I created my template as the below

```
@using Kendo.Mvc.UI
@(Html.Kendo().NumericTextBox()
.Min(0)
.Decimals(0))
```

Now, to use that as an Editor Template in Razor syntax, I attach it to a column as below:

```
columns.Bound(p => p.SomeField).EditorTemplateName("NumericTextBoxEditor");
```

All works fine and I have my numeric text box that doesn't allow non-numeric input. If I try the same thing by declaring columns in Javascript, I can't get it to work. Is there any way to set the correct editor template e.g.

```
var myColumns = [];
myColumns.push({
  width: 100,
  editor: "NumericTextBoxEditor"
});
```

Or will it never know about the editor template due it being server side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Or will it never know about the editor template due it being server
>   side?

This is correct.

In JS, [column.editor](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/grid#configuration-columns.editor) has to be a function, so you can't directly use server-side editor templates. The equivalent would be something like this:

```
columns: [{
    field: "fieldName",
    editor: function (container, options) {
        var input = $('<input name="' + options.field + '" />');
        input.appendTo(container);
        input.kendoNumericTextBox({
            min: 0,
            decimals: 0
        });
    }
}],
```

Comment: Absolutely what I was looking for. Thanks Lars